# Proxying an RTSP url using an RTSP Proxy Server

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp, proxy-server, live555

I have a use case where I need to restream an RTSP URL.

> For all the below cases, Live555 is built locally by cloning the source.
>
> For all the below cases, required ports are opened for RTSP in respective servers.

First I set up a file to be streamed using `Live555MediaServer`. This is in an AWS instance (AWS1).

`./Live555MediaServer ashi.webm` gives

`rtsp://public_IP_of_instance:8554/ashi.web`

I check whether an incoming stream is working or not, by trying to play it in VLC player. This incoming stream is working fine and playing well on VLC.

Now, to restream, I tried Live555ProxyServer. Now incoming stream from AWS1 is restreamed to another URL by running Live555ProxyServer on my Mac.

`./Live555ProxyServer rtsp://public_IP_of_instance_one:8554/ashi.web` gives,

`rtsp://localhost:8554/ProxyStream`

This URL is also playable in VLC.

Now I setup another AWS instance (AWS2) and run ProxyServer on it, listening to AWS1.

That is,

`./Live555ProxyServer rtsp://public_IP_of_instance_one:8554/ashi.web` gives,

`rtsp://public_IP_of_instance_two:8554/ProxyStream`

This URL is not playable.

I tried using `-t` flag for TCP instead of UDP. I tried checking the incoming RTSP stream with `ffprobe` and the stream is showing all the required details.

What could be the possible reason? What is the missing piece in this pipeline? Do we've great industry-grade open source RTSP servers?

EDIT:

I don't know what is exactly happened, but using VLC as the client to check the stream was the problem. I moved to `ffmpeg` and tried to write it to a file using

`ffmpeg -i rtsp://public_IP_of_instance_two:8554/proxyStream -acodec copy -vcodec copy abc.webm`

So the stream from `ProxyServer` is fine.

The lead to the change of client was the repeated warning from `live555ProxyServer` about outdated firmware explained [here](http://live-devel.live.narkive.com/4EApE0qw/rtcpinstance-error-hit-limit-when-reading-incoming-packet-over-tcp-increase-maxrtcppacketsize).

I'm currently using VLC Version 3.0.3 Vetinari (Intel 64bit) in Mac which is the latest version. Maybe VLC is using an old version of `Live555` internally.

Comment: Have you managed? I'm trying to do the same and bumped on this question. You setup seems kinda complex, so I'd be grateful if you can point me some tips/tutorial